# How to tension toilet handle nut without handle sticking?

Tags: repair, toilet

I have to replace toilet handle assemblies frequently. However, the frustrating part is if you tension the nut at all, the toilet handle will not return to its original position.  I'm left leaving the nut barely hanging on and in fact it often later falls off.

Is there something I'm missing? A washer or spacer I should be putting on?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what hardware you're using. Try wrapping the threads with pipe dope or teflon tape to act as a locknut.

Answer (score 3):

Buy the kind that look like this:

[image: http://www.infoskep.com/subject-how-to-install-a-toilet-handle.html]

Notice the 'ears' that wont allow it to sink into the hole and the full length square body that would make it impossible to over tighten it (at least, not enough to inhibit functionality - you'll have broken it way before then).

If I had to guess, you're still using metal ones or you're dealing with offset (angled) toilets, the handles for which are also available in plastic.

There's lots of different kinds out there. I think you're getting the wrong replacement type for the kind of toilets you have.

Comment: +1 for nut that locks on the handle and not the tank. -1 for some really scary looking water in that tank.

Comment: +1 this is exactly right. Remember that the handle arbor and nut are likely *left-hand* thread. What's up with that nasty water BTW? I tell my kids the tank water is clean and you could drink it in an emergency... maybe not so much... LOL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it sounds like something is missing, a bushing perhaps, or you might be missing a lock ring. Not all handles are identical, but in general, the idea is to mount a threaded pipe to the toilet.

[image]